# creating sqlite database on device using AndroidStudio

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I currently working on my school assignment. I currently facing some issue on creating a SQLITE DB when debugging my app.

**logcat:**

```
E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) os_unix.c:30046: (2) open(/data/data/com.asus.microfilm/databases/Sugar.db) -
E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Failed to open database '/data/data/com.asus.microfilm/databases/Sugar.db'.
```

I wondering why it open up the other package DB. I have search some example online and I couldn't find any solution that's why I decided to post it here.

Besides, I have already used **adb-shell** and I found nothing in my package.

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() + "/" + DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
```

**tab1.java**

```
DatabaseHelper myDb;
myDb = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
```

my tab1.java is a fragment.

Comment: updated on the `context.getExternalFilesDir` I want to save it to my SDcard but when i open up my `package>files` in DDMS still nothing

Comment: what you want to do ?

Comment: You want to save the db else where ?

Comment: I'm trying to save my *.db file into my SD card. Due to my phone is not rooted. I unable to access the `data>data` folder in my internal storage

Comment: who said you that you can not access the data> data folder ?

Comment: Oh are you talking about the real device ?

Comment: Hi @CoasMckey yes sir.

Comment: @CoasMckey I do try before in my emulator by using GenyMotion, the *.db file is successfully created. But when comes I try to debug on my physical device. It cames out totally different and I can't even find the *.db file.

Comment: check my answer and let me know if it works

Comment: please try out both code , these should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and let me know if it creates the file there

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, context.getExternalFilesDir("MyDatabase") + "/" + DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
```

or you can try this too if want to use internal memory , as its more secure

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, context.getFilesDir() + "/" + DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
```

**Update 1: Try Using this**

```
 public DatabaseHelper(final Context context) {
    super(context, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + FILE_DIR
            + File.separator + DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

Comment: Nope, checked by using DDMS. :(

Comment: in which directory you are looking for ?

Comment: `storage>MicroSD>Android>com.user.myassignment2v04>Files`, am i correct?

Comment: no You are searching in wrong directory , may be the databse is creating by the solution I suggested but as you are searching in wrong path You can not find it , ,

Comment: I have added the Log so that you can see what is the exact path , and also share me that path in the comment

Comment: Tried the first one an `MyDatabase` Folder created, but when click the expand button in the DDMS, nothing's there.

Comment: I log by using `context.getFilesDir().getPath().toString()` logcat shows: `/data/data/com.user.myassignment2v04/files`

Comment: so in that case you can not drive through this folder of device as yo can not see this folder

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.user.myassignment2v04/files/MyDatabase`

Comment: yeah there should be your file , ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,have you write permission in Manifest ? 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: I have WRITE permission but no READ.

Comment: by checking the ddms for the external storage the *.db file should be appeared right? Mine still does not appear. :(

Comment: Yes man, now I go and tried the other way round first. Create a new empty project with ONLY sqlite and see it works or not.

Comment: can you please update your code , with my update1 code , I wanted to see how you have implemented it , because this is working in my app.

Comment: I do update already, replace `FILE_DIR = "com.user.myassignment2v04"` check with DDMS but nothing is shown.

Comment: where do you have updated your answer i cant see

super(context, context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath()

Answer (score 1):

my solution for example

```
public class NotesDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    private static final String DB_NAME = "NotesFile";
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Notes";
    private static final String COLUMN_KEY = "key";
    private static final String COLUMN_NOTE = "note";
    private static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    private static final String COLUMN_QUESTION = "question";
    private String table = "";

    public NotesDB(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- onCreate database ---");
        db.execSQL("create table "+TABLE_NAME+" ("
                + "id integer primary key autoincrement,"
                + COLUMN_NAME+" text,"
                + COLUMN_KEY+" integer,"
                + COLUMN_QUESTION+" text,"
                + COLUMN_NOTE+" text" + ");");
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

usages

```
SQLiteDatabase db = new NotesDB(getAppContext()).getWritableDatabase();
        c=db.query("Notes", null, selection, selectionArgs , null, null, null );................
```

Comment: Hi @latsenko Anton, I tried it. Can't works! When I launch the app, straight away show stopped. :(

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
```

Comment: Hi @walkmn, I had tried this. It does not work and I don't know why. When I check my logcat back it shows `/data/data/com.asus.microfilm/databases/Sugar.db` which is totally different from my package.

Answer (score 0):

SQLiteOpenHelper have two constructor:

```
SQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String name,    SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version)


SQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version, DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler)
```

You have to implement one of them,and create tables in onCreate method.